# Can Expected value of perfect information be zero?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-programming, assignment-problem

I tried to find the Expected Value of Perfect Information (EVPI) and the Value of the Stochastic Solution (VSS) of the following problem.

> Consider a farmer who specializes in raising wheat, corn, and sugar beets on his 500 acres of land. During the winter, he wants to
> decide how much land to devote to each crop. The farmer knows that at least 200 tons (T) of wheat and 240 T of corn are
> needed for cattle feed. These amounts can be raised on the farm or bought from a wholesaler. Any production in excess of the
> feeding requirement would be sold. Over the last decade, mean selling prices have been \$170 and \$150 per ton of wheat and
> corn, respectively. The purchase prices are 40% more than this due to the wholesaler’s margin and transportation costs. Another
> profitable crop is sugar beet, which he expects to sell at \$36/T; however, there is a quota restriction on sugar beet production.
> Any amount in excess of the quota can be sold only at \$10/T. The farmer’s quota for next year is 6000 T. Based on past
> experience, the farmer knows that the mean yield on his land is roughly 2.5 T, 3 T, and 20 T per acre for wheat, corn, and sugar
> beets, respectively. 
> (a) Let “above” and “below” average indicate a selling price 10% above or below the mean selling price

[image]

To help the farmer make up his mind, we can set up the following model. Let
$x_1$ = acres of land devoted to wheat,
$x_2$ = acres of land devoted to corn,
$x_3$ = acres of land devoted to sugar beets,
$w_1$ = tons of wheat sold,
$y_1$ = tons of wheat purchased,
$w_2$ = tons of corn sold,
$y_2$ = tons of corn purchased,
$w_3$ = tons of sugar beets sold at the favorable price.
$w_4$ = tons of sugar beets sold at the lower price.

\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
 \hline
\text{Scenario} & \text{Wheat} &\text{Corn} &   \text{Beet}\\ \hline
\text{Above average}&187 &165&39.6\text{ OR }11\\ \hline
\text{Average}&170 &150&36\text{ OR }10\\ \hline
\text{Below average}&153 &135&32.4\text{ OR }9\\ \hline
\end{array}

I used Lingo to solve this LP,

```
! objetive function Z for best scenario;
Min = 150*x1+230*x2+260*x3+(238*y1-187*w1)+(210*y2-165*w2)-39.6*w3-11*w4;
!land constraint;
x1+x2+x3 <= 500;
!Wheat constraint;
2.5*x1+y1-w1 >= 200;
!Corn constraint;
3*x2+y2-w2 >= 240;
!Sugar beet constraint;
w3+w4 <= 20*x3;
!Quota constraint;
w3 <= 6000;
!non-negative constraint;
x1 >= 0;
x2 >= 0;
x3 >= 0;
y1 >= 0;
y2 >= 0;
w1 >= 0;
w2 >= 0;
w3 >= 0;
w4 >= 0;
```

Solution: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,w_1,y_2,w_2,w_3,w_4)^T=(120,80,300,0,100,0,0,6000,0)^T$ and $z_{\text{min}}=141900$

```
! objetive function Z for average scenario;
Min = 150*x1+230*x2+260*x3+(238*y1-170*w1)+(210*y2-150*w2)-36*w3-10*w4;
```

Solution: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,w_1,y_2,w_2,w_3,w_4)^T=(120,80,300,0,100,0,0,6000,0)^T$ and $z_{\text{min}}=118600$

```
! objetive function Z for below average scenario;
Min = 150*x1+230*x2+260*x3+(238*y1-153*w1)+(210*y2-135*w2)-32.4*w3-9*w4;
```

Solution: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,w_1,y_2,w_2,w_3,w_4)^T=(120,80,300,0,100,0,0,6000,0)^T$ and $z_{\text{min}}=95300$

But my WS (wait and see solution) and EEV (expected value of expected value problem) have the same solution and $z_{\text{min}}$ which implies EVPI = $0$. Isn't EVPI need to be non-zero?

---

Can anyone help me to understand what **E**xpected value of **E**xpected **V**alue problem and **R**ecourse **P**roblem actually do/mean?

Comment: I think there are errors in your LP model. I don't see the source of the first three terms in your objective function, and I think your cost to buy wheat or corn (for feed) should be 140% of the scenario price, not of the average price. Fixing those may not change the EVPI result, though.

Comment: Also, your "average" and "below average" objective functions appear to be identical.

Comment: Sorry for the typos @prubin. I add the definition of every variable.

Answer (score 1):

EVPI needs to be *nonnegative*; it does not need to be strictly positive. Suppose, for example, that you have an LP model with three scenarios. The variable vector is $x$, the constraints are identical across scenarios, and the objective function is to optimize $f(x)$ in one scenario, $\lambda f(x)$ in another, and $\mu f(x)$ in the third ($\lambda$ and $\mu$ being positive constants). Since the objective functions are scalar multiples of each other, the optimal solution $x^*$ for the first scenario will also be optimal in the other two scenarios, and so information about which scenario applies will not change the solution. Thus the EVPI will be 0.

**Addendum**: Now that the problem statement is fixed, we can pin down what is going on. I think your model is wrong, in that the purchase price of wheat and corn should presumably inflate or deflate with the scenario (for instance, 140% of 90% of 170 for wheat in the below average scenario). That appears not to make a difference as far as EVPI is concerned.

It turns out that growing wheat or corn is cheaper than buying it in all three scenarios, given the planting costs and yields. So you buy nothing in all three scenarios.

Next, look at the relative profitability of wheat and corn. Corn has a higher yield but also a higher planting cost than wheat. In the "average" scenario, wheat is more profitable, so you will only plant enough corn to cover the cattle feed requirement. Sale prices would have to increase 220% (not one of your scenarios) for corn to become attractive.

Similarly, beets sold at full price are more attractive than wheat unless prices drop to about 37% of average (again, not one of your scenarios), so you will plant 300 acres of beets in all scenarios. Beets above quota are money-losers unless prices rise at least 30% (not a scenario), and at that point they would still be inferior to wheat. So in all scenarios, the planting scheme is the same, and therefore the value of information is zero.

If you have scenarios with more extreme price swings, you would eventually get a nonzero EVPI.

Comment: Thanks for your response @prubin. Okay, $\lambda f(x)$ and $\mu f(x)$ give a nice idea. Isn't my case different from this? As the objective function is not fully scaled by some constant? Can you help me to understand what **E**xpected value of **E**xpected **V**alue problem and **R**ecourse **P**roblem actually do/mean? Thanks again for your response.